# (Memory-efficiently) implement `sorted` as a generator

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, generator

I guess this is not a particularly new topic and I guess there are better implementations than mine: I am looking for (a) the kind of / type of algorithm that I am dealing with - its actual name or similar - and (b) potentially a better implementation.

The general problem: Imagine a list `a`, which is very long - too long for fitting into memory more than once. The list contains a "random" sequence of things that allow to be sorted (`<`, `>` and `==` are working). I want to iterate over all entries in the list, including duplicates, in ascending order, but without copying the list or producing anything that is of similarly "extreme" length. I also want to maintain the original order of entries in `a`, i.e. an in-place `sort` is ruled out. So I basically want to minimize the memory required for sorting while not modifying the original data source.

Python's sorted does not touch the original data but produces a new list, having the same size / length as the original. Therefore my basic idea is to re-implement `sorted` as a generator:

```py
def sorted_nocopy_generator(data_list):
    state_max = max(data_list)
    state = min(data_list)
    state_count = data_list.count(state)
    for _ in range(state_count):
        yield state
    index = state_count
    while index < len(data_list):
        new_state = state_max
        for entry in data_list:
            if state < entry < new_state:
                new_state = entry
        state = new_state
        state_count = data_list.count(state)
        for _ in range(state_count):
            yield state
        index += state_count
```

It can be tested as follows:

```py
import random

a_min = 0
a_max = 10000
a = list(range(a_min, a_max)) # test data
a.extend((random.randint(a_min, a_max - 1) for _ in range(len(a) // 10))) # some double entries
random.shuffle(a) # "random" order
a_control = a.copy() # for verification that a is not altered

a_test_sorted_nocopy_generator = list(sorted_nocopy_generator(a))
assert a == a_control
a_test_sorted = sorted(a)
assert a == a_control
assert a_test_sorted == a_test_sorted_nocopy_generator
```

It scales O(N^2), just like bubblesort for instance. What kind of algorithm am I looking for? How can this thing be optimized (probably by trading *some* memory)?

Comment: in-place sort:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Comment: Why do you want to maintain the original order?

Comment: About "trading some memory": How much extra memory can you afford? And how long is the list?

Comment: @RafalS And your point is?

Comment: @HeapOverflow The question is how much do I have to trade to get any meaningful improvement whatsoever? I'd limit this to one order of magnitude less than the size of the original data though.

Comment: "order of magnitude" and "size of the original data" really make me wonder what your objects are. If they're somewhat big, then `sorted` might already fit the requirement, as it only duplicates the references to the objects, not the objects.

Comment: I thought you're looking for in-place sort on list to not create a copy and save memory. That's what list.sort method does.

Comment: @RafalS Thanks for the suggestion. I am not looking for `list.sort` I am afraid.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Nothing crazy big, but it really does not matter for this question. Let's say 10% if the length of the original list. But in more broader terms, my interest really is to understand how much extra memory in relation to my original data would get me how much extra performance.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Thinking about your comment, if the stuff in the original list is not copied, just the list (i.e. the references / pointers - as a shallow copy), you only need memory for about 64 bit / 8 bytes per pointer (plus some meta data). That's correct. But let's just say that's not an option either.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you use 32-bit Python and each object is 56 bytes (which they easily might be), then `sorted` already only only adds about 10% memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sketch here.  Where `N = len(data_list)`, and `S = sqrt(N)`, uses `O(S)` extra memory and takes worst-case `O(N*log(N))` time:

- For each consecutive slice of length `S` in the original data, copy that slice into a temp list, use `.sort()` to sort it in place, then write the result to a unique temp file.  There will be about `S` temp files in all.
- Feed those temp files into `heapq.merge()`.  That's a generator, keeping track of only the `S` currently-smallest values across the `S` inputs, so this part also has `O(S)` memory burden.
- Delete the temp files.

The more memory you can use for this, the fewer the temp files needed, and the faster it will go.

### Cutting the constant factor

As noted in the comments, there's scant hope for a sub-quadratic time algorithm.  However, you can do a whole lot to cut the constant factor in your original algorithm by cutting the number of passes over the data.  Here's one way,  producing the next `K` entries on each pass over the data.  It remains quadratic-time overall, though.

```
def sorted_nocopy_generator(data_list, K=100):
    import itertools
    from bisect import insort

    assert K >= 1
    total = 0
    too_small = None

    while total < len(data_list):
        active = [] # hold the next K entries
        entry2count = {}
        for entry in data_list:
            if entry in entry2count:
                entry2count[entry] += 1
            elif ((too_small is None or too_small < entry) and
                  (len(active) < K or entry < active[-1])):
                insort(active, entry)
                entry2count[entry] = 1
                if len(active) > K: # forget the largest
                    del entry2count[active.pop()]
        for entry in active:
            count = entry2count[entry]
            yield from itertools.repeat(entry, count)
            total += count
        too_small = active[-1]
```

### And eliminating the worst cases

As in @btilly's answer, the worst cases in the code above can be sidestepped by using a max heap instead.  Then adding a new entry to `active` has worst-case time `O(log(K))` instead of `O(K)`.

Luckily, the `heapq` module already supplies something usable for this purpose.  But dealing with duplicates becomes something of a headache then - the under-the-covers max heap `heapq` uses isn't exposed.

So the following special-cases the largest of the smallest `K` entries of interest, using `.count()` (as in your original program) to do a full pass to count how many there are.

But instead of needing to do that for *every* unique element, it only needs to do it once per `K` elements.

Extra memory use is proportional to `K`.

```
def sorted_nocopy_generator(data_list, K=100):
    import itertools
    from heapq import nsmallest

    assert K >= 1
    too_small = None
    ntodo = len(data_list)

    while ntodo:
        if too_small is None:
            active = nsmallest(K, data_list)
        else:
            active = nsmallest(K, (x for x in data_list
                                     if x > too_small))
        too_small = active[-1]
        for x in active:
            if x == too_small:
                break
            yield x
            ntodo -= 1
        count = data_list.count(too_small)
        yield from itertools.repeat(too_small, count)
        ntodo -= count
        assert ntodo >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok, dumping to disk is always an option, but one that I was not trying to look into. If I wanted to maintain order of the original data, I could just dump it (or some information on its original order) to disk. `heapq.merge` is interesting though.

Comment: @s-m-e Maybe sort each slice of length S with your own method instead. I think that would be O(NS) time and O(S) memory.

Comment: If you want sub-quadratic time, you need to build on a sub-quadratic sorting algorithm.  There are lots of those, but all I'm aware of rely on "remembering" (explicitly or implicitly) all they can deduce about the results of prior comparisons.  That means lots of extra info to store, whether via rearranging the original order (like heap or quick sorts) or planting pointers all over  the place (like tree sorts).  I wrote Python's `list.sort()` algorithm, so you can trust that my knowledge of such things isn't shallow ;-)

Comment: You are being modest.  Yes, you wrote Python's sort, but it was such an improvement that the algorithm has been adopted in lots of other languages as well and wound up with a Wikipedia page at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort.

Comment: What constant factor is your "Cutting the constant factor" solution cutting? It seems to me to take n/k passes, each taking up to nk steps, for a total of n^2 steps. Granted, the k in "nk steps" is for list insertion, which is super fast. Are you disregarding it because of its speed?

Comment: You can plug this in the OP's program and see that it's very much faster, given their test data. The original does two passes for each unique entry (`.count()` does a full pass of its own). The "up to" in your "up to nk steps" is important; only contrived - or "unlucky" - data will reach nk steps.  On average, for the OP's test data, `active` is mutated in only about 4.2% of `for` loop iterations.  So that's more like nk/25 steps.

As in @btilly's answer, `active` could be replaced with a max heap instead - and should be if `K` gets into the thousands. Else a simple list is plenty fast.

Comment: See edit using a max heap (implicit in `heapq.nsmallest()`).

Comment: That's a really neat solution. Thanks a lot! Just one last "off topic" question: Do you think it makes sense to add a generator-version of sorted to the core language?

Comment: You could float it on the python-ideas mailing list, but I don't expect it would get traction. It just doesn't come up. What _does_ come up is sorting an iterable so long that not even the original sequence can fit in RAM. Then the first suggestion here (merge sorted slices stored in temp files) is "the standard" approach.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that you have memory for `k` things in a separate list.  Then the following will scale like `O((n + n^2/k) log(k))`.  In the extreme cases of `k` constant it is quadratic and if `k` is a fixed fraction of `n` then it is `O(n log(n))`.

The idea is to create a buffer of the `k` smallest things that you have not yet returned.  Turn it into a min-heap and then use heap operations to return things from it in time `O(log(k))` per element returned.  When the buffer is empty, refill the buffer then proceed as before again.  (The buffer starts empty.)

To create the buffer you scan the array, putting in things larger than the last returned until you have reached `k` things in the buffer.  Then turn it into a max-heap, and replace things in the heap when they are larger than what is returned, and smaller than what is already there.  When it is refilled, reorganize it into a min-heap.

You will need to refill the buffer `n/k` times.  Each time is a `O(n log(k))` operation worst case.  (If `k << n` and the array is in random order then the average run time is `O(n)` because almost everything is compared to the max in the heap and then dropped.)

*Important edge case:* If you have duplicates, you need to account for the case that your buffer only included some of the copies of the largest thing.  One approach is to keep track of how many copies of the largest thing should be in the heap but were not actually stored there.  That way after you empty the heap you can return all of the missing duplicates as well, then proceed with scanning for larger elements.